# I have a Fujitsu Siemens AMILO Pro V3515 laptop. Where can I get the proper drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, laptop, via

I have been using Ubuntu for several weeks now. (With some prior Linux usage.) Several programs I have used have given me this error message: `Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".`

I think the error may be caused by not having the proper drivers. How can I fix this issue?

Edit:

lspci | grep VGA gave me this output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 [Chrome 9 HC] (rev 01)
```

There are no additional drivers installed. I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: what is your graphics card (`lspci | grep VGA`) and have you installed any graphics drivers (Additional Drivers window)? What version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @fossfreedom sorry, I didn't notice your comment. I added the info above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VIA graphics are supported by the "[OpenChrome](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenChrome)" open-source graphics drivers.

Unfortunately, these graphics cards are not supported by the manufacturer for Linux.  The open-source graphics drivers are not actively developed.

I've checked out the [x-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=oneiric) and [x-stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=natty) - the version has not changed between Natty and Oneiric.

Three ubuntu choices:

1. Accept the issues
2. trade in your laptop for a intel/nvidia/ati graphics laptop
3. join the via graphics team and help out development which [looks very dead](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ODk4Nw) at the moment...

Comment: So... Does this mean I should do video stuff on another computer?

Comment: depends upon what you mean "video stuff" - if you want to play games - probably not.  Day to day browsing, libre office work etc - should work OK.

Comment: I tried Blender... It didn't work... cocos2d... Didn't work... Voodoo match mover... didn't work. Other than that, Firefox has worked, and so has MuseScore. I think Gimp has worked as well. Plus, I developed a website using PHP, MySQL, and Apache (which obviously didn't use graphics.) Thanks!

Comment: yep - graphics intensive stuff like those apps you will have issues with.  Blender in particular also has some issues with ATI graphics.